# Identically vanishing polynomials in infinite commutative rings

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, determinant, roots, nilpotence

Let $R$ be an infinite, characteristic zero, commutative ring. I can furthermore suppose it is reduced and indecomposable (no nontrivial nilpotents and idempotents).

**My question is whether there is a nonzero polynomial $f\in R[x]$ which is identically zero on $R$, when $R$ has no nontrivial nilpotents or idempotents.**

Note: it is easy to show that there are polynomials with infinitely many roots, let $R=\mathbb Z[s]/(2s)$ and consider $f\in R[x]$ given by $f(x)=sx^2+sx$. All integers are roots of $f$.

But my question is whether we can have $f$ vanishing on all of $R$, not just on an infinite subset.

On the other hand, if we further mod out by $s^2$, turning $f$ (I believe) identically vanishing, we create a nilpotent element.

A technique that I tried is trying and produce a Vandermonde matrix $V$ associated to the elements of $a_1,...,a_k$ of $R$ that be a nonzero element, so that $V$ multiplied by the matrix of coefficients of the canonical basis $e_i$ of polynomials of degree up to $k$, with the its $i$-th element replaced by the coefficients of $f$, $f_i$'s, would have two proportional columns and yield, $\det V\,f_i=0$ and therefore, if I can manage to make $\det V$ regular, I will get $f_i=0$.

But I believe we may have reduced rings where all elements are zerodivisors, so I am currently trying to modify this Vandermonde argument, by using the very coefficients of $f$ as $a_i$'s and create a nice Vandermonde lattice.

Comment: FWIW the second example at [On polynomials having more roots than their degree](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/on-polynomials-having-more-roots-than-their-degree/) would *almost* qualify, except the ring has non-trivial idempotents.

Comment: Very nice indeed, dxiv. Everything in this boolean thing is an idempotent and its own opposite. This is infinite but has characteristic two, a further quotient of $\mathbf{Z}_2[\{x_i\}_{i\in \mathcal{P}(X)}]/(x_i^2=x_i)$

Comment: I toyed with the idea of using different set operations such as to avoid nilpotents and idempotents, but didn't find anything obvious offhand. Thought I'd leave the comment here, maybe someone else does.

Comment: For coefficient rings with idempotents we also have standard examples in characteristic zero like $(1,0)x^2-(1,0)x \in (\mathbf{Z}\times \mathbf{Z}_2)[x]$ but I must say yours is nicer.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The existence of more roots than the degree of the polynomial necessarily implies the existence of zero divisors: Let f(x) have degree n, and let $r_1$, $r_2$, ..., $r_n$ be zeros of f(x).  Then f(x) factors thus: (x - $r_1$)(x - $r_2$)...(x - $r_n$) [at least in some extension field of R].  If $a$ is *another zero* [i.e one different from $r_1$, $r_2$, ..., $r_n$], then in R, ($a$ - $r_1$)($a$ - $r_2$)...($a$ - $r_n$) = 0, whereas none of the parenthesized factors is zero.

Or at least, I THOUGHT characteristic zero precluded zero-divisors.

Comment: I allow zerodivisors, I just do not allow nontrivial nilpotents and idempotents.
Characteristic zero does not preclude zerodivisors(think of Z X Z).

Your argument only works for domains. In general, if r_1,...r_n are roots of f, you can divide out f by each (x-r_i) but not necessarily more than one at once. If f(x)=(x-r_1)g(x), and f(r_2)=0, then 0=(r_2-r_1)g(r_2) and if R is not a domain, you cannot conclude g(r_2)=0

Just consider my example sx^2+sx in (Z[s]/(2s))[x]. For all integers m, f is divisible by (x-m), yet of course it cannot be divided out by more than two at once.